# "Problems encountered by people learning English"

Tags: discussion

I've read the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) about questions that are welcomed here. But I'm not sure what *kinds* of problems encountered by people learning English can be asked here. After all, "how to improve my English", which is absolutely not welcomed, may also be a *problem* encountered by a student when s/he is learning English.

For instance, students who are struggling with GRE verbal test, especially those whose first language is not English, may like to know what kind of reading materials (magazines, journals, etc.) are good for preparing their GRE. What categories should this kind of questions belong to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'What reading materials are useful in preparing for my GRE?' belongs in the *off-topic* category, relating neither to the English language nor to how it is used.  The only question on that sort of test that I can imagine being on-topic (and not general reference) would be "The test says X is the correct English in this situation; surely Y is possible or even better?"  But even then it's more suited to an education forum than a site like this.

Answer (score 1):

A question such as "How do I improve my English?" is not enough scoped, and it is rather subjective because it depends from the person asking the question. The [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) says:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an *entire book* that answers your question, you're asking too much.

Questions about books, magazines, journals, or online resources, are never-ending questions for which a new answer can be added all the times a new resource is available. In the case the questions is asking for *the best* resource, the question would be subjective. The problem is that in such case, there would not be any expertise required for answering (Is there an expert about the best resources for students of English as ESL?); in this case, a user who already answered the question could change the given answer all time a new resource is available, which would become the new best resource.